# Which should I use on SharePoint 2010 list item forms? JQuery or InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, infopath, jquery

I'm editing some SharePoint 2010 list item forms using InfoPath 2010 and some with JavaScript/JQuery. I know that Microsoft will not support InfoPath after SharePoint 2013. InfoPath is easy to use to edit item forms and can use some simple rules to interact with user; but can not do whatever I want to. JQuery is not as easy as InfoPath but I can do whatever I want to such as animations and more. I can use SPServices to add/update list items but this takes longer than InfoPath.

What are pros and cons of InfoPath and JavaScript/JQuery? Which should I use at new projects? Is there any other alternative?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Microsoft will support InfoPath for years to come. The support ends 2023. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Microsoft%20InfoPath%202013&Filter=FilterNO

Answer (score 0):

Even though InfoPath might be the easier and faster choice I would still say go with JavaScript. this is mainly because of an update scenario, where Client Side Rendering comes into the picture in SP 2013+.

Personally I doubt that InfoPath will survive the years to come, however that is just speculation from my side. Microsoft's road is clear, APPS and CSR is the new black :)